# :after & :before background img not showing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a frame design to a div like the example below :

[Gold frame div design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfpri.png)

I tried doing this with background image but doesn't work like I want it to because it has to be responsive. Now I'm trying to do this with (:before & :after) but the images won't appear. Am I leaving a line of code behind or something? Help appreciated!

**Problem :** [Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzJCr.png)

//HTML

```
<div class="second-section">
<div class="container">
  <div class="purp-box">
    <h1>Welcome to my site!</h1>
    <p>Some text goes here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

//CSS

```
.purp-box {
  height: 303px;
  background: url(../images/box-background.png);
}

.purp-box:after,
.purp-box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.purp-box:before {
  width: 67px;
  height: 303px;
  background: url(../images/purp-left-border.png) no-repeat;
  right: 100%;
}

.purp-box:after {
  width: 67px;
  height: 303px;
  background: url(../images/purp-right-border.png) no-repeat;
  left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'd probably use [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) for that to begin with ... Anyway, please create a [mcve] - without having your specific images available, this is hardly reproducible.

Comment: Although, might simply be the `right: 100%`/`left: 100%` positioning ... that places the pseudo elements _outside_ of their parent, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, all I had to do was add (box-sizing: border-box;) & (position: relative;) to the main div. Thank you for suggesting image-border as well.

```
.purp-box {
  height: 303px;
  background: url(../images/box-background.png);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
```